# Error when using SAGA's "topographic correction" algorithm in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga, topography

I'm trying to do topographic correction of Landsat images using SAGA's "topographic correction" algorithm from QGIS' processing toolbox. I was able to do it using Minnaert Correction with slope and cosine correction, but when I try C-correction I get the following error:

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\saga\dll\gdal_MrSID.dll
127: Impossibile trovare la procedura specificata.

and no image is created. 
Anyone has any idea about how to solve this?

In alternative I wanted to use GRASS' "i.topo.corr", but it seems like it's not available in the Processing toolbox?

I am using QGIS 2.10.

Comment: You can ignore the error message: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14509 There must be another reason for not creating the image.